# area of triangle in tetraedron

Tags: geometry

In my book there is a question . As given below .

[image]

In this I wanted to know how they have written the first equation  about area of triangle BCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will label the plane and its associated area vector with the same color.

[image]

Since they are mutually perpendicular, we can form the vector diagram on the top right. (After joining some of the necessary points, a cuboid is formed.)

The following color coded names are vectors.

Area of $\triangle BCD$ = magnitude of the vector normal to that plane
= |Red-dotted| = |Red| = |purple + green-dotted| = |(brown + blue) + green|.

Comment: Nice figures , but in the cube can you mark the points A ,B ,C

Comment: How the area is equal to magnitude of the vector normal to plane

Comment: @koolman As requested, I have the figure updated. Note that the blue vector (for example) is along the direction of AC, but its actual location is not that important.

Comment: @koolman You can verify that by letting AB = h. Then, AC = 2(3)/h, AD = …. . Area of BCD can be found after all lengths are known.

Comment: @koolman For your further info, the face of the cuboid cut by the vertical plane through (green and red-dotted) happens to be a square.